# Why the check on installation date in M2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cli, deployment

So i've build a CI/CD process that worked perfectly on Magento 2.0
After upgrading to 2.1, stuff started to collapse.

I use Magento's CLI commands to create env.php dynamically, depending on the stage where it's deployed onto.
Unfortunately this does not set the install date, and since Magento 2.1 this seems to be required before Magento includes any other code than it's own.
This makes it hard to deploy Magento, because i don't want to install on every deployment. And i don't want any credentials in my VCS either.

Using a template is an option, but i'd rather not if i could deploy fully using the CLI tools that Magento provides.

So my question is, why the check on this date before any custom code is included? 
And is there a workaround to fully deploy Magento 2.1 (not to install!), using Magento's CLI commands?

Answer (score 0):

We have created functionality which allows to deploy without Magento installation. Please keep in touch with last 2.1 patch Magento version. Im hope my answer will be helpful for you.